# How to update release details using github action when publishing release?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want my github action to update the name of a release when it is published using [oktokit.rest.repos.updateRelease](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v19#repos-update-release)

Apparently updateRelease requires the release_id. Is there some context variable that contains the release_id during this release publish process? Or do I first need to get a reference to the release using [getReleaseByTag](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v19#repos-get-release-by-tag) instead to get the ID?  Maybe getReleaseByTag won't even work until after the release is first published?

update.yaml:

```
name: update release name
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
jobs:
  update-release-name:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - uses: actions/github-script@v6
    with:
      script: |
        github.rest.repos.updateRelease({
          owner: context.repo.owner,
          repo: context.repo.repo,
          release_id: ?????????    <-- NEED RELEASE ID         
          name: 'Some New Name'
        })
```

Comment: Why couldn't you use the release drafter? 

Comment: It needs to be scripted so can't just edit in the gh web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the github release_id by storing it in an environmental variable, and then grabbing the variable in the script for easy access like so:

```html
name: update release name
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
jobs:
  update-release-name:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - uses: actions/github-script@v6
    env:
      RELEASE_ID: ${{ github.event.release.id }}

    with:
      script: |
        const { RELEASE_ID } = process.env
        
        octokit.rest.repos.updateRelease({
          owner: context.repo.owner,
          repo: context.repo.repo,
          release_id: `${RELEASE_ID}`,
          name: 'Some New Name'
        })
```